# Migrate a website and keep the URL structure with WordPress

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am making a migration of a website and I need to keep the current URLs which have the following structure

/florida/tampa-bay/shop

/ohio/woodmere/shop

I solved the first and second part with a taxonomy (state) and a custom post (retailer) associated to it but I still can't figured out the last part which shows the store of a specific retailer.
Any ideas will be welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a good side for this question.  If you look in the StackExchange network map, you will see the Webmasters and Wordpress Development sites, either of which would be a better place to ask.